# View-based NSTableView yields odd results with bindings and delegate

Tags: objective-c, macos, osx-lion

I have an NSTableView, the content of which is bound to an arrayController using a filterPredicate.  The tableView is view-based, so its delegate is set to an object that has the

```
- (NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row
```

method.  I'm getting odd behavior, which may be related to my observation that this method is being called even when the controller's number of arrangedObjects is 0.  Moreover, each time the method is called, the number of rows it asks for is the total number of objects in the array controller's content (as opposed to arrangedObjects).  It think it may be because of this that when I set the objectValue of the cellView requested using

```
cellView.objectValue = [arrayController arrangedObjects] objectAtIndex:row];
```

that it is often the wrong one.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I still can't explain why the view was behaving as it was, but I did manage to get things to behave correctly, doing the following:

- binding tableView content to arrayController's arrangedObjects
- binding various elements of the tableCellview used in the tableView to the appropriate keyPath of the tableCellView's objectValue
- providing each tableCellView as follows (where BILSelectableRoundedTableCellView happens to be a subclass of NSTableCellView):

  ```
  (NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row {

  NSInteger numberOfObjects = [self.arrayController.arrangedObjects count];

  if (numberOfObjects == 0)
      return nil;

  if (row >= numberOfObjects)
      return nil;

  BILSelectableRoundedTableCellView *viewForTableColumnRow = [self.myTableView makeViewWithIdentifier:@"DataCell" owner:self];

  return viewForTableColumnRow; }
  ```

Finally, using a datasource that implements the following:

```
(id)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row {

NSInteger numberOfObjects = [self.arrayController.arrangedObjects count];

if (numberOfObjects == 0)
    return nil;

if (row >= numberOfObjects)
    return nil;

return [self.arrayController.arrangedObjects objectAtIndex:row]; }
```

The use of the later seems contrary to the documentation out there, but is necessary to get things to work properly.  Interestingly, the other datasource method (numberOfRowsInTableView) is not called when using bindings, although it is called when i'm not using bindings.

Answer (score 1):

objectValueForTableColumn is not necessary for the case of bindings.  Just banged my head against a wall for a few minutes and came back with this path of least resistance:

1) bind your NSOutlineView content to the NSTreeController (arrangedObjects controller key)

2) bind the subviews of each of the NSTableCellView to the enclosing NSTableCellView (objectValue.foo where foo is the key path for your target field)

3) set the identifier for each column in your outline view (I do this for tracking reordering of table columns between launches)

4) make sure each NSTableCellView has the identifier set to Automatic (or is the same as the table column) ** This is important and messed with me **

5) when you call makeViewWithIdentifier: make sure you pass tableColumn.identifier

This assumes you only have one cell view type per table column.  Otherwise, you'll need to pass in the correct identifier for the cell view you want in makeViewWithIdentifier:.